# Coercivity of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $V$ Hilbert space. $T:V\rightarrow V^{\prime}$ a single-valued nonlinear operator.

I have see in this paper [enter link description here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0362546X14001187) page 67 ..this sentence "the operator $T$ is strongly monotone which also implies that $T$ is coercive" ..

How can we show that if $T$ is strongly monotone implies that $T$ is coercive? whithout having this assumption $T(0)=0$.

Comment: Could you provide the definitions of coercive and strongly monotone?

Comment: This depends on how we define coercivity. If coercivity is $\langle Tu,u\rangle\geq c\|u\|^2$, then an counterexample would be $T(u)=u+v$ for some fixed $v\neq0$. If coercivity is $\langle Tu,u\rangle/\|u\|\to\infty$ as $\|u\|\to\infty$, then the statement is true. (As for the second definition of coercivity, you may check out [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054188/coercivity-definitions))